# Adding/removing some tabs and line breaks in an HTML code using sed

Tags: sed, newlines, html

I want to refine an HTML code using sed, as an extra refinement procedure after refining it using HTML Tidy, as HTML Tidy doesn’t look flexible enough for some requirements.

I used this command to add some tabs and/or line breaks to some tags and remove them from others:

```
s/<li>/\t&/g
s/\n<\/li>/<\/li>/g
```

1. The first command worked fine unless `li` has an attribute, so, how can I target an opening tag regardless of whether it has an attribute or not?
2. The second command didn’t work at all. I want here to put the closing tag `</li>` at the end of the previous line.

Comment: `\r` is carriage return. `\n` is line-feed. Which line-ending do you have in your file? You say `\r` but then use `\n` in the sed.

Comment: Well, it was my fault, I’m sorry; I was applying HTML Tidy and sed respectively from the same input to the same output :) I changed the question now.

Comment: @don_crissti exactly.

Comment: @AnasR. Is this linux or OSX?  It makes a difference.

Comment: @John1024 Linux.

Comment: The version of `tidy` on my system (tidy version 20091223cvs-1.5) joins `<li>...</li>` lines by default, no need for `sed`.   I also tested the latest version of `tidy` from http://www.html-tidy.org/ (version 5.2.0) and it does the same.

Comment: @cas I tried it using both; they both do not join them.

Comment: your html input must be seriously weird, because I can not manage to make either version of `tidy` fail to join `<li>` ... `</li>` without specifying a tiny wrap margin (`-w 10`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this sample file:

```
$ cat sample.html 
<li a=x>Point One
</li>
<li>Point Two
</li>
```

I believe that this `sed` command does what you ask (this may require GNU sed):

```
$ sed -Ez 's|<li\b|\t<li|g; s|\n</li\b|</li|g' sample.html
        <li a=x>Point One</li>
        <li>Point Two</li>
```

#### How it works

- `-E`

  Use extended regex.
- `-z`

  Read nul-delimited data.  Since a proper html file has not nul-characters, this has the effect of reading in the whole file at once.
- `s|<li\b|\t<li|g`

  This puts a tab in front of every occurrence of `<li` followed by a word boundary.
- `s|\n</li\b|</li|g`

  This replaces every occurrence of newline followed by `<li` followed by a word boundary with `<li`.

#### A variation: putting `<li>` on its own line

```
$ sed -Ez 's|<li[^>]*>|&\n|g; s|\n</li\b|</li|g' sample.html
<li a=x>
Point One</li>
<li>
Point Two</li>
```

#### Obligatory warning

html can be complex and these `sed` commands are only intended to work on simple cases.

Comment: Great, thank you so much. I am still new here to vote up your answer :)

Comment: It seems it doesn't target the whole opening tag. Suppose we want to add a line break after the opening tag, I tried `s/<li\b>/<li\b>\n/g` and `s/<li\b>/\n&\n/g`, but didn't work.

Comment: @AnasR. OK.  I added code for that.